# The method or operation is not implemented while using linq to nhibernate

Tags: c#, linq-to-nhibernate

i m trying to use linq to nhibernate 3  and i have made following linq query

```
 var a = (from c in Session.Query<ChoiceValue>()
                 join Specific in
                     (
                         (from choicevaluelocale in Session.Query<ChoiceValueLocale>()
                          where
                            choicevaluelocale.UICulture == "en-GB"
                          select new
                          {
                              choicevaluelocale.ChoiceValue.ChoiceGroup.ChoiceGroupName,
                              choicevaluelocale.ChoiceValue.ChoiceValueId,
                              choicevaluelocale.DisplayName,
                              choicevaluelocale.Description
                          }))
                       on new { c.ChoiceGroup.ChoiceGroupName, c.ChoiceValueId }
                   equals new { Specific.ChoiceGroupName, ChoiceValueId = (Int32)Specific.ChoiceValueId } into Specific_join
                 from Specific in Specific_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     c.ChoiceGroup.ChoiceGroupName,
                     ChoiceValueId = (Int32?)c.ChoiceValueId,
                     SpecificValueDisplayName = Specific.DisplayName,
                     SpecificValueDescription = Specific.Description,

                 }).ToList();
```

but while executing it on n-hibernate in c# i got following error

```
The method or operation is not implemented
```

stack trace is

```
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitGroupJoinClause(GroupJoinClause
   groupJoinClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, 
   QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1  
   bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Data.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel  
   queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
   at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor   
   sessionFactory)
```

can any one please help me to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the Linq to Hibernate library you're using is incomplete. Somewhere a `NotImplementedException` is being thrown. Are you using a stable release?

A quick poke around the internet says that group joins and subqueries in selects are not supported. You're using a group join in your example, hence the exception. Specifically, the following post(s):

1. http://ayende.com/blog/4083/nhibernate-linq-1-0-released
2. <strike>http://guildsocial.web703.discountasp.net/dasblogce/2009/07/29/LinqToNHibernateJoins.aspx</strike> (**LINK IS DEAD**)

In the NHibernate 3.1 source code, the method that is throwing your exception looks exactly like this:

```
public override void VisitGroupJoinClause(GroupJoinClause groupJoinClause, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**UPDATE**: As of version 5.1.x, NHibernate's LINQ provider still [does not support](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/341a864d049ba0d95bc37ccdc627cbe882760fe1/src/NHibernate/Linq/Visitors/QueryModelVisitor.cs#L499) this operation.

Some solutions suggest writing your own HQL (like raw SQL) instead of the Linq syntax.

Comment: i m using nhibernate 3.1 which has built in libraries for linq to NHibernate

Comment: The library is not complete. I dug through the source code; the `NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitGroupJoinClause()` method has no implementation, meaning Group Joins are not supported. You'll have to re-work your Join or use straight SQL.

Comment: Freaking NHibernate...